# Setting a value, then changing it one second later

Tags: java, game-engine, game-physics

Right now I'm working on a sort of space-invaders style game. You move the character to the y coordinate where the enemy is, and shoot.

There is four windows that the player will shoot at. There will ALWAYS be an enemy in one of them.

So here is how the code would work:

```
enemylocation = 1;
*CHANGE VALUE EVERY X SECONDS
if(enemylocation==1){
enemy.draw(x, y, size);
}
if(enemylocation==2){
enemy.draw(x, y, size);
}
if(enemylocation==3){
enemy.draw(x, y, size);
}
if(enemylocation==4){
enemy.draw(x, y, size);
}
```

What would the timing code/method be?
Thanks

Comment: And your question would be?

Comment: Not related with your question, as you didn't asked yet. What will be the benefit of the if conditions if the all do the same functionality! Change it to `switch` statement, actually, you don't even need any condition.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
  while(true) //Makes the code run forever
  {
    enemylocation++; // increments 1
    Thread.sleep(1000); // Waits one second
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most people would use a Swing timer to update code over a given time interval. I would use the java.Math.Random Class to change the number to 1-4.

```
public class game implements ActionListener{

    Timer enemyUpdate;
    int enemylocation;

    public game(){

    enemyUpdate = new Timer(1000, this); //1000ms = 1s

    enemyUpdate.start();


    }

    public void actionPerformed(){

        //utilize math.random to change enemylocation every second

    }

}
```